# how to create a php web service which accepts a string and perform database operations

Tags: php, web-services

I am trying to create a **php web service**. I am new to PHP. I am having a Java Application, which is having 2 string variable. This need to be stored in Server database to access for the php applications running from server. So I need to put it in the server. So I need to create a web service. Is it possible to send data to web service? is it possible to write data to database using the web service?

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow! take a look at **Related** at bottom right of this page, it will give you some ideas for start.

Comment: so the java app has the data and the php app needs to access it, right? So you have to write a java service and access it via PHP. So it's rather a Java question than a php questin. Check out how to create a REST service in Java.

Comment: Didn't understand the fact it was Java<>PHP communication. My answer below contains an example from 1 server to another both communicating using PHP. First chapter of the text contains an explanation on how to use this with other languages. Hope this helps

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The example below illustrates a simple api/webservice in PHP (both server & clientside)**

If there's need for a java client side (I just see that someone commented it might be the case), then you'd need to find a way to scramble the response in a way you can handle it with java. For example, if your communicate with PHP in the form of javascript jQuery. The response of the webservice would mose likely contain a json response which can be understoob by javascript. I'm not familiar with java..

**Lets start**

Your question is kind of odd in the way you describe what you want. As far as I'm concerned a *web service* is an application running on a server, which kan handle actions based on incoming requests (get/post/raw data. These actions can be fetching data, modifying data or registering data. Also this can mean there's a database involved or a textbased file to save the data to/get the data from.

If that is what you mean, then yes.. it's possible. Let's say *server a* is containing your data model and a list of actions `add`, `get` andn `delete`. First thing you might want to think of is some kind of security for your service. A basic security example is to use a webserver-key. I usualy use a random md5() generated string. Of course this isn't the best security you can take, since everyone who knows the key could use it, but I'll get back to this later on.

Besides security of access to your webserver, also consider the way you want to ship your data. You can choose to send a post/get request to your service using cURL but that would contain all open data. Another option (a little bit more scrambled) is by serializing before sending it along.. and one step further you might want to base64_encode your string. This, at least, creates an unreadable parameter of data which is transfered to your webserver. In the best case your create a custom key which is available at the webservice and de server which is communication with the webservice. This key scrambles your serialized parameter and can be used to descramble the response/parameters on both service/user side of your webapp.

Now that we know there's another server requesting data from our webservice, we can also add another layer of security to the "webservice key". Every request to your webservice will send some parameters along (like `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`) these can be used to pair a key with a server IP or domainhost. This puts a limit on the amount of users that might can get access to your service.

Now, how would a very basic example look like?

First of, the webservice. You can use an OO-way handling incoming requests based on a parameter, but you could also use plain PHP files:

http://www.webservice.com/api-contacts.php

- Required parameter: action
- Optional parameter: id & name

Sending a request to api.php using $_GET['action'] = 'get' and $_GET['id'] = '2' would most likely return a response containing the contact with id '2'.

For requesting this data there are a few options. Most basic are file_get_contents or cURL. I consider cURL to be the better, since there are far more options you can change to get exactly what you want.

Considering this is your script on clientside:

```
$param = array();
$param['action'] = 'get';
$param['id'] = 2;
$params = base64_encode(serialize($param)); // generates a scrambled string

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.webservice.com/api-contacts.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLTOP_POSTFIELDS, 'data='.$params);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Of course, api-contacts.php would be base64_decoding the $_POST['data'] string first and then unserializing the result:

```
$data = unserialize(base64_decode($_POST['data']));
```

followed by some checks:
- is $data['action'] valid?
- if yes: are the needed parameters found (id for delete/get, name for add)
- if yes: perform the field checks (valid name, valid id)
- if yes: insert, delete or get the result
- if yes: return the response

Also the response would be an array, for example

```
$response = array(
  'result' => 'success',
  'data' => mysql_fetch_assoc($getUser) // obviously this is just to illustrate there's userdata in the 'api-contacts.php?action=get&id=2' request.
);
```

Last but not least, don't forget to unserialize & base64_decode your `$result` string on client side.

This is a basic explaination of how I implement a simple webservice to share data across domains on different servers. Ofcourse I'm open to all kinds of improvements and tips from other people.

// Little add-on:

The reason why I serialize and base64 encode my response is because an array can't be send as text-response, also the serialized string might cause problems when received by the client.

The serialization & base64 encoding of the parameters isn't neccesary, it's just a little bit of extra security while transfering the data over the http protocol. Just using the CURL_OPTPOSTFIELDS as '?action=get&id=2' would do fine aswel! Or perhaps you want the service to use friendly urls and create the url `www.webservice.com/api-contacts/get/2` for example.

As response type there are a few common things:
1) XML response
2) JSON response
3) base64_encoded serialized array

But, in some cases a simple text response 'ok' would be enough. Or you might want to build your webservice to understand HTTP header reponses like '200 OK'.

Comment: A great answer! Deserves to be upvoted more than once, imo. I'd make the minor point that the original question is rather vague and under-researched, and there would have been value in encouraging some prior effort before giving such a full answer. Nevertheless, +1.

Comment: I guess the top/bottom of the answer already illustrate the diversity of situations a PHP webservice can be used in. Just use a universal response type (xml/json/text) in order to work between two languages. Luckily PHP offers enough options to support this with their functions :)

Comment: Thank u very much for your answer!! I appreciate your willingness to answer. +1 for it.. I will go through it thoroughly.

Comment: It helped me.... I know that  I did not ask it properly. My intention was to provide the data captured by a client-side Java application to PHP application. I am a Java developer. Not familiar with web technologies. Your answer helps me a lot. Now I have found a solution with the help of your answer..