# passing variables to and fro between two different pages on two different servers

Tags: php

I want to pass variables between two servers in php like A will send to B then B will do something with that and pass the result to A then A will do something with that based on the result and pass the result to B and so on.
This is the code on server A. It passes email to B and storing the result in $result.

```
$Email = $_POST['email'];
$postdata="&email=$Email";
$useragent= "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)" ; 

$ch = curl_init("http://www.gguproject.hostoi.com/handler.php"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent); //set our user agent 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); //set how many paramaters 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$postdata); //set data to post 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$result= curl_exec ($ch); //execute and get the results 
curl_close ($ch);
```

This is the code on server B. I am not able to pass the query result stored in $row back to server A.

---

```
<?php 
require_once('database_connection.php') ;
ini_set ("display_errors", "1");  
error_reporting(E_ALL);  
$error = array();
$email = $_POST['email'];
if(!empty($email))
{
    $check;
    $query_check_credentials = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE (Email='$email') AND Activation IS NULL";
    $result_check_credentials = mysqli_query($dbc, $query_check_credentials);
        if(!$result_check_credentials)

        {
            print 3;
        }
        if (@mysqli_num_rows($result_check_credentials) == 1)//if Query is successfull 
        { // A match was made.




            $row= mysqli_fetch_array($result_check_credentials, MYSQLI_ASSOC);//Assign the result of this query to SESSION Global Variable
            print 2;
            $POST['name']=$row['Username'];

        }
        else
        { 
            print 1;

        }

}
?>
```

Comment: this is a security issue. imagine a site doing this with your banking information.

Comment: You're using mysqli, why aren't you using prepared statements instead of string interpolation?

Comment: I did a little how-to on a REST service in another question, perhaps it clears some things up for you. Also on a security perspective: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15656027/how-to-create-a-php-web-service-which-accepts-a-string-and-perform-database-oper/15656464?noredirect=1#comment22223988_15656464

Comment: I know this is a security issue. It is a project for educational purpose only nothing professional. 
Is there any better way of passing variables between two servers I mean communicating with some remote server.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass information from B back to A, you should echo it in B. `$result` will contain this as a string. I suggest using JSON format.

On B, instead of printing 1, 2, 3 as status, put it in a `$status` variable, e.g.

```
$status = 3;
```

At the end, do:

```
$result = array('status' => $status, 'data' => $row);
echo json_encode($result);
```

On A, you can then do:

```
$result = curl_exec ($ch);
$data = json_decode($result);
```

You can then use `$data['status']` to get the status code, and `$data['data']` to get the row.

Comment: not getting any output I tired to echo $data on server A "blank"

Comment: What do you get if you echo `$result`?

Comment: {"status":2,"data":{"Memberid":"28","Username":"ritesh","Email":"sangwan.ritesh@yahoo.in","Password":"deflection","Activation":null}}
it is an encoded value but after decoding I echo $data blank. echo $data['status'] blank

Comment: That looks right. See my update to see how you should use this.

Comment: read the comment above yeah already used this echo $data['status'] blank output.

Comment: What does `var_dump($data)` say?

Comment: This makes no sense. If `$result` contains the correct JSON, I don't see why `json_decode($result)` doesn't contain the corresponding array. Do you have error reporting enabled?

Comment: obviously its not the real password.
visit ggutpa.net84.net
and use sangwan.ritesh@yahoo.in as email you will see
first I echo $result then var_dump($data)